Boost serialization context
The "magic" boost serialization methods
template<typename Archive>
void load(Archive & ar, unsigned version);

template<typename Archive>
void save(Archive & ar, unsigned version);

are fine until I need to pass context information in. For example to look up some external resource when restoring some state. What's the simplest way to have something like
template<typename Archive>
void load(SerializationContext * context, Archive & ar, unsigned version);

without breaking things?

... fork the boost serialization library? Or smuggle information in using a threadlocal variable.

@Botje why not just put the state in the archive implementation. It's absolutely the design of the library

Note: this answer uses C++17, but it should be applicable to earlier versions with some modifications.
Simplest way I can think of is to use a wrapper class for the value:
template <typename Object>
struct WithContext {
    WithContext(Context& context, Object& object)
        : context(context), object(object) {}

    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned int version) {
        object.serialize_with_context(context, ar, version);
    }

    Context& context;
    Object& object;
};

Then, instead of defining serialize in your type, you define serialize_with_context:
struct GPSPosition {
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize_with_context(Context& context, Archive& ar,
                                const unsigned int version) {
        // do stuff
    }

    // ...
};

Then you can use it like so:
// Write
ar << WithContext(context, object);

// Read (can't read into r-value)
WithContext helper(context, object);
ar >> helper;

// Either (can't read into r-value)
WithContext helper(context, object);
ar & helper;


PS: if you want to be able to use ar & WithContext(context, object), you can define an operator:
template <typename Archive, typename Object>
void operator&(Archive& ar, WithContext<Object>&& wrapped_object)
{
    WithContext helper = wrapped_object;
    ar & helper;
}


Does this work with class hierarchies, or is it going to choke on ar << boost::serialization::base_object<BaseClass>(*this)?

@jg_at_pharos The usual approach here would be that you first decide whether this is actually what you need (in which case I'd argue that really you just serialize more objects than you were previously). In that case, try it out. Post a new question if you run into a problem with that (you can link the new question in a comment here)
